# Jquery Drag and drop to arbitray location

Tags: jquery, drag-and-drop, z-index

I've got a situation where a user needs to be able to drag and drop an image onto a section of a dynamically generated portion of a page that will will always be enclosed with `<pre> </pre>` tags but will have no other information.

The only way I can I think to accomplish this is to add a wrapper div with a different z-index, but is it even possible to "drop" this item on an arbitrary location on the layer above the pre-formatted text?

Any suggestions/ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think, in code, you need to open tags with <.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you seen the JQuery UI.  You can literally in its simplest form to do this:

```
$("#MyDragElement").draggable();
```

AND

```
$("#MyDropElement").droppable();
```

http://jqueryui.com/

Documentation:

http://docs.jquery.com/UI

Check it out: :-)

Andrew